# How to set multiple listener rules to load balancer in AWS?

Tags: amazon-alb

I have set multiple listeners and rules for an internet-facing ALB as below

[image]

The 80 port only redirect to 443. On 443, I set two kinds of different rules with different target groups.

If I access /* path on my domain, it can forward to targetgroup1. But when I access /static/* path it got a 503 error.

If I change the order between /* and /static/*, I can access /static* but the /* got a 503 error.

Why can't they work together? How to set correctly?

Comment: ordering is important. /static is part of /* so it will go to rule targetgroup1 with your current rule. you need to list out all specific path first, then /* path, then the last default action